# PHP Explode , adding variables to URL

Tags: php, url, variables, explode

Ive used explode on a user input variable to get an array of search terms.
These search terms need to be added to the end of a URL in the following style = 
www.example.com/$search[0]%20$search[1]

However, I dont know how many search terms theres going to be, eg there could be 5, or there could be 1, and if I add 5 search[] variables to the end and the user inputs 1 search term, I get 4 errors for the missing variables.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)?

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of `explode` is [`implode`](http://php.net/implode). Use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url .= implode("%20", $search);
```

That's really all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function with `%20` as the delimiter, and your params array as the data.

this will return a string that consists of all the array values concatenated with `%20` in between them

Answer (score 1):

PHP already comes with a handy function to build query strings.. look up [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` to check if the variable exists. It also works on arrays. See the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php